# Windows 10 does not revert to 8.1 - simply boots back into Windows 10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

Customer's machine originally running Windows 8.1 automatically upgraded to Windows 10 a few days ago.

The profile immediately had a corrupt Tile Repository after the upgrade, which I repaired using the instructions [here](http://www.urtech.ca/2015/09/solved-fix-windows-10-start-button-does-nothing-in-10-minutes/).

When I attempt to revert to Windows 8.1, it asks all the usual questions, then restarts. It seems like a command window pops up for a split second after the first reboot, then it reboots again back into Windows 10.

I also tried "Go back to previous build", but get the message:

`We ran into a problem and won't be able to take you back to the previous build.`

I would like to avoid doing a full factory restore if at all possible.

Any ideas as to what could be preventing the downgrade?

Comment: Probably easier in the long run to just cave and pave the machine.

Comment: I fear you're right. Hopefully I can avoid that path.

Comment: "The following actions will disable Go Back to previous Windows option:
•Refresh
•Reset
•Disk Cleanup (if it touched Windows.old or $windows.~bt)
•Manually deleting files within Windows.old or $windows.~bt
•Running on battery (must be plugged in)

If you have performed any of the action listed above you won’t be able to get go back option." [source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/rolling-back-to-win-7-after-win-10-upgrade-we-ran/4ce795d9-afc3-4ca8-a3f6-916e9c9320eb)

Comment: I have checked, and Windows.old and $Windows.~bt folder both exist, and seem to have their original contents within them.